# Error in setting laravel project in another PC locally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in laravel. My friend gives me a project to study, but when I set that project on my localhost I receive some error. Can Anyone help me to set that project on my PC.
I Uploaded the server file code[enter image description here][1]

**

**Error: Warning: require_once(C:\wamp64\www\hazir/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\hazir\server.php on line 21 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\hazir/public/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\hazir\server.php on line 21**

**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

    $uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: what's the error code ? can't see the image

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\wamp64\www\hazir/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\hazir\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\hazir/public/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\hazir\server.php on line 21

Comment: The error message looks pretty straight forward to me!  Do you have a file in `C:\wamp64\www\hazir/public/index.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you alter the Laravel app and created a file `server.php`. and accessing files via URI on the public directory of Laravel. Unfortunately, that's not how Laravel application works.

I assumed you're using a [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/), by using this, it may cause you a bit of trouble in setting up Laravel app on your machine. I highly suggest using [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) or the Laravel created [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead)

Comment: do you help me setting laravel project with wamppserver

Comment: Always make sure that you have [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), then go to your Laravel app, I assumed it's in the `hazir` directory. 
Run `cmd`, so you can run `composer install`, or in "THAT" _(C:\wamp64\www\hazir\)_ directory you press SHIFT+(RIGHT CLICK ON YOUR MOUSE) then pick the _Open Command Prompt window here_. A command prompt will popup, then run `composer install`. It will install dependencies in the `vendor` directory. However, it seems that you said, "another pc", you can then copy the `vendor` directory of _that another pc_ and paste it there.

Comment: Wampserver have __Virtualhost Management__, you can name the virtual host whatever you like, but the __Complete absolute path__ should look like this C:\wamp64\www\hazir\public\ After you restart the DNS or the apache, you are good to go.